Dart DateTime timezone offsets differ between date specified and DateTime.now()
Basic dart question about DateTimes that I'm having trouble with. Specifically this code:
void main() {
  print('OFFSET: ${DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset}'); // OFFSET: -4:00:00.000000
  print('OFFSET2: ${DateTime(2021).timeZoneOffset}'); // OFFSET2: -5:00:00.000000
}

This works the same in dartpad as in plain dart from the command line. I'm just trying to understand why they give me a different value.

The difference are most likely Daylight saving time (DST) since DateTime(2021) would create a day (01-01-2021) in the winter season (where we don't have DST) while DateTime.now() would create a date (27-04-2024) in the summer season (where lot of countries do have DST).
You can try print the name of the timeZone:
void main() {
  print('OFFSET: ${DateTime.now().timeZoneName}');
  // OFFSET: Romance Daylight Time
  
  print('OFFSET2: ${DateTime(2021).timeZoneName}'); 
  // OFFSET2: Romance Standard Time
}

